# Exclusion-inclusion principle- task.

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

How many such numbers in 5-digit decimal expansion such that:
(1) 3rd digit is 7 and digit 5 there is neither time or 
(2) there is no number more than once.
My solution:
Let a set $A$ is a set of numbers satisfying (1),
Let a set $B$ is a set of numbers satisfying (2)
Let's calculate $$| A | = 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$$
And now:
$$| B | = 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$$
Now, if these numbers in $A$ that satisfy $B$, de facto:
$$| A \cap B | = 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$$
Thus, in principle, inclusions and exclusions:
$$| A \cup B | = 9 \cdot 8^3 + 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 -8 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 17040$$
OK?

Comment: Can the first digit be $0$?

Comment: Please explain how you got $|B|=9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$ instead of $9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6$.

Comment: How did $8\cdot9\cdot9\cdot9$ turn into $9\cdot8^3$?

Comment: The number must be 5-digit so 0 can't be the first.
In case B you right, the: $|B| = 9\cdot9\cdot 8 \cdot 7\cdot 6 $ 

"How did $ 8\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9 $ turn into $ 9 \cdot 8^3 $"

I made mistake, to correct is $9^3 \cdot 8 $

And now is ok?

Comment: In $A\cap B$ there are $7$ choices for the first digit, since it can't be 0, 5, or 7. Then there are $7$ choices for the second digit, since it can't be 5 or 7 or repeat the first digit.

Comment: yes, you also alright. And now? :)
$ | A \cap B  | = 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot  5 $

Comment: I think you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, there are three errors in the calculation.

1. For $|B|$, the choice of the non-zero first digit still leaves $9$ digits to choose from, so $|B|=9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6$.
2. For $|A\cap B|$ we have to avoid both $5$ and $7$, and again $0$ in the first digit, which leaves $7\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$ choices.
3. In the last equation you wrote $9\cdot8^3$ instead of $8\cdot9^3$.

So the correct total is

$$
|A\cup B|=8\cdot9^3+9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6-7\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5=31578\;.
$$